# What does "group over group" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Namely, I have the notation, for groups $G,H$, that $\frac{G}{H}$.

The details is that ,

> Let $G,H,A$ be groups. Then If $H \triangleleft G$ and $A \subseteq G$ then $H \cap A \triangleleft A$ and $\frac{A}{H \cap A} \cong \frac{HA}{H}$

Now, apparently, this is a restatement of the first isomoprhism theorem for groups,

Which I am familiar with in the form

> Let $G,H$ be groups and a homomorphism $\theta:G \to H$ with kernel $N=ker(\theta)$ then $N \triangleleft G$ and with $Im(\theta) \leq H$, there is an isomoprhism $\phi$
>
> $$\phi: G/N \to Im(\theta)$$

So, questions

1. How is the first statement saying the same thing as the second? Is $H:=N$? But even so, why are there three groups $G,H,A$? The second statement only has two.
2. Now, $G/H$ is the quotient group(i.e. the left/right cosets of $H$). But $\frac{G}{H}$? What's that? $G,H$ are...well, "sets" with an operation yes? Purely seeing them as a set of elements doesn't make sense to literally "divide."

Very confused. The first statement in from chapter $14$ of Ian Stewart's Galois theory 4th edition by the way. Second from personal lecture notes in uni.

Can someone clear up the two questions for me please?

And here's another

> If $H \triangleleft G$ and $H \subseteq A \triangleleft G$ then $H \triangleleft A$, $A/H \triangleleft G/H$ and
>
> $$\frac{G/H}{A/H} \cong \frac{G}{A}$$

is apparently the second isomorphism theorem. Does the last one mean...$(G/H)/(A/H)$?
[image]

Comment: $\frac{G}{H}$ is just a bad way to write $G/H$.

Comment: Let me add something more... it still seems bizarre to me

Comment: This is a rather weird question: the notation for quotients of groups more or less evidenty copies the one for fractions, and it should be apparent that $\frac45$ and $4/5$ denote the same thing (and the former is not a «bad way» to write the latter in any sensible sense!)

Comment: The first boxed theorem is often called the Second Isomorphism Theorem, and the last boxed theorem is often called the Third Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: I just added the picture of the page and bit I am talking about; so it's actually a typo do you think? it says first and second isomoprhism theorem so...supposed to be the second and third then